# Playing VLC while gaming

Tags: video, graphics-card, vlc-media-player, gaming

I've discovered that, for certain games (such as Assassin's Creed IV), in order to play video in VLC and game at the same time on a separate monitor you have to change the video mode of VLC. I currently have VLC set to OpenGL, but it's a noticeable difference--clicking into and out of fullscreen my whole display flickers, it takes longer to load videos, etc.

My question is this: Is there a video mode that works best for VLC that will also allow me to watch it while gaming?

*(My apologies if this should be asked at Arqade, but it seems to be more VLC-oriented than gaming-oriented so I'm asking here.)*

Answer (score 3):

The video mode performance is probably related to the bottlenecks of your system.  For example, OpenGL typically runs on your GPU, if your GPU is fully utilized while playing Assassin's Creed IV then you might get better VLC performance from using CPU rendering.  On the other hand, if your CPU is completely pegged while gaming you might actually get better performance from OpenGL.

Your best bet is going to be experimentation on this question, try a few different video modes, and see which gives you the best performance, it could be different system to system.